# Capture group of number with regex

Tags: php, regex, pcre

im trying to capture a group of number behind the "**image**" word in the url

this is the url `http://example.com/image123456/super_moon_image_2`

and this is my expectations `http://my-example.com/get.php?123456`

im using this code its work for some url but the result will broken if there is another number on the url.

```
$link = 'http://example.com/image123456/super_moon_image_2';
$re = '/[^0-9]/';
$str = preg_replace($re, '', $link);
echo 'http://my-example.com/get.php?' . $str;
```

can someone help me correct the regex
thank you.

Comment: Is it always after the "image" word? You can try to match `(?<=image)\d+`.

Comment: is `example.com` hosted by you? Then you could use a htaccess rewrite instead of php-regex stuff.

Comment: yes it always "image" but with this (?<=image)\d+ it will remove the numbers.

Comment: @dognose no its not, i've edit the domains in my question so it doesn't make confusion

Comment: @Angel You need to match `(?<=image)\d+`, not replace it.

Comment: @ahmed sorry im new to regex things, i've trying with this method, the result is an array, is there any way around? can you show some example? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex pattern:

```
(.+?)image(\d+).+
```

And replace with `$1get.php?$2`.

Here's a [**regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ZhwEEw/2).

I don't know much PHP, but your code should look something like this:

```
$link = 'http://example.com/image123456/super_moon_image_2';
$re = '/(.+?)image(\d+).+/m';
$subst = '$1get.php?$2';
$newlink = preg_replace($re, $subst, $link);
echo $newlink;
```

[**Live PHP example**](http://rextester.com/NSFSTR37113).

Comment: wow thanks, it is bit a different and i have to change the $subst = '$1get.php?$2'; to $subst = '$2'; to suit my need. thanks again for saving my day